# disable showing unchange value in TextInput

Tags: react-native

I am using Farsi/Persian/Arabic digits on my TextInput. when I started typing, at first the unchanged number showed then changed it to the proper digit. My TextInput needs to stop showing the unchanged value. when I delete **value** and **defaultValue** my TextInput still is showing the typed value by **onChangeText** and **onChange**.

```
  <TextInput
    // value={digitsEnToFa(value)}
    onChangeText{(text)=>setValue(digitsEnToFa(text))}
  />
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The font I used for my TextInput, did not contain Persian(Farsi) digits. Therefore, I changed the font family, and the problem was solved!